# I want to send integer,String,Object,double,Bitmap,HashMap from one activity to another in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am begnning in android , I want to send String,Object,double,ArrayList from one activity to another . I already done with integer but when i want to send other data like object and ArrayList i am facing problem.

SenderActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("intVariableName", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: Are u facing problem while sending arrayList?

Comment: I think he is facing the problem there as other types are basically provided by the API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Passing double data:**

SenderActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("doubleVariableName", doubleValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
double doubleValue = mIntent.getDoubleExtra("doubleVariableName", 0.00); // set 0.00 as the default value if no value for doubleVariableName found
```

**Passing String data:**

SenderActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("stringVariableName", stringValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
String stringValue = mIntent.getExtras().getString("stringVariableName");
```

or

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
String stringValue = mIntent.getStringExtra("stringVariableName");
```

**Passing ArrayList data :**

SenderActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
myIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("arrayListVariableName", arrayList);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
arrayList = mIntent.getStringArrayListExtra("arrayListVariableName");
```

**Passing Object data :**

SenderActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("ObjectVariableName", yourObject);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
yourObj = mIntent.getSerializableExtra("ObjectVariableName");
```

*Note : Keep in mind your custom Class must implement the Serializable interface.*

**Passing HashMap data :**

SenderActivity

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
Intent mIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
mIntent.putExtra("hashMap", hashMap);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();    
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)
mIntent.getSerializableExtra("hashMap");
```

**Passing Bitmap data :**

SenderActivity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("image",bitmap);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

ReceiverActivity

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap = mIntent.getParcelableExtra("image");
```

Comment: Thanks,Its very useful .

Answer (score 2):

You can send object one activity to another by using Serializable class

check following example:
http://hmkcode.com/android-passing-java-object-another-activity/

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-send-object-from-one-activity-to-another-activity/

you can send like:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, activity.class);
    intent .putExtra("Key",product);
    startActivity(intent );
```

and get value like:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();`enter code here`
    product = (ClassName) bundle.getSerializable("Key");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a bean of the data you want to send like this

```
public class YourBean implements Serializable {

String yourString;
Object yourObject;

double yourDouble;
ArrayList<String> yourList;

public String getYourString() {
    return yourString;
}

public void setYourString(String yourString) {
    this.yourString = yourString;
}

public Object getYourObject() {
    return yourObject;
}

public void setYourObject(Object yourObject) {
    this.yourObject = yourObject;
}

public double getYourDouble() {
    return yourDouble;
}

public void setYourDouble(double yourDouble) {
    this.yourDouble = yourDouble;
}

public ArrayList<String> getYourList() {
    return yourList;
}

public void setYourList(ArrayList<String> yourList) {
    this.yourList = yourList;
}
}
```

then when you want to pass data in intent do like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    YourBean yourBean = new YourBean();
    yourBean.setYourString("your string");
    yourBean.setYourDouble(Your double);
    yourBean.setYourObject(Your Object);
    yourBean.setYourList(array list);
    intent.putExtra("bean",yourBean);
    startActivity(intent);
```

then you can get it like this in your SecondActivity like this

```
YourBean yourBean1 = (YourBean) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("bean");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intents. In a intent you can put all sort of data, String, int, whatever you want.

In your case, in activity1, before going to activity2, you will store a String message this way :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("message", message);
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity2, in onCreate(), you can get the String message by retrieving a Bundle (which contains all the messages sent by the calling activity) and call getString() on it :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String message = bundle.getString("message");
```

Then you can set the text in the TextView or where you want

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
ArrayList<String> mArray = new ArrayList<>();
mArray.add("Mon");
mArray.add("Tue");
mIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("Array", mArray);
startActivity(mIntent);

// In AboutActivity.java recieved data
ArrayList<String> mArray= getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("Array");
Toast.makeText(AboutActivity.this, ""+mArray, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```